# Show that if $j \in A$ then there exist $k \in$ {$-1,1$} and $i \in A$ such that $kj \equiv 3i\pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p=601$, which is prime and let $A=\{1,2,...,300\}$.
How do I show that if $j \in A$ then there exist $k \in$ {$-1,1$} and $i \in A$ such that $kj \equiv 3i\pmod p$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $j^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $j$ modulo $601$ (which exists, because $601$ is prime). Note that for any $a$, either $a\in A$ or $-a\in A$ (up to congruence modulo $601$). This is because if $a\notin A$, then $a\in[301,600]$ so $-a\equiv601-a\in[1,300]$.
If $j\cdot3^{-1}\in A$ we can take $i=j\cdot3^{-1}$ and $k=1$.
If $j\cdot3^{-1}\notin A$, then $-j\cdot3^{-1}\in A$ so we can take $i=-j\cdot3^{-1}$ and $k=-1$.

Comment: I do not understand the last assertion, namely if $j3^{-1}$ $\notin$ $A$, then $-j3^{-1} \in A$. Please explain ! Thanks!

Comment: @satokun See edit. Note that I am implicitly identifying $A$ with $A+601\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

We basically want $k$ and $i$ to satisfy $j \equiv 3ik \mod p$, or $401j \equiv 401 \cdot 3 ik = 1203ik \equiv ik \mod p$. Now note that $ik$ can take all nonzero values in $\mathbb{Z}/601\mathbb{Z}$ to finish the argument.